# If I get banned from a community will it stop showing up in Hot Questions?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, ban

If I get banned from a single community (as opposed to all of SE) will that communities hot questions stop appearing in my feed?

I like Hot Questions but due to [train wreck theory](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=train%20wreck%20theory) I've clicked into a few of them and I keep getting these sites in Hot Questions. I like Hot Questions as it shows me questions from new-to-me sites that I do find interesting which are outside of my usual interests.

There are some feature requests, workarounds, and user scripts to tune Hot Questions but I'd rather just not see these sites at all.

Comment: I doubt HNQ is personalized so the answer is probably No.

Comment: If the only way to avoid starving is to go to jail... Well...

Comment: SE has no such thing as a ban anyway. At worst, you'd sit with a looooong suspension.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Hmm. Isn't account deletion the same as a ban? ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill not having an account or deleting an account doesn't work. I don't have an IPS account and I deleted my Academia account. I still see those in the Hot Questions sidebar. The duplicate link appears to solve my problem, albeit with some effort.